# Detecting every pixel of jQuery scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the following code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

When I scroll very quickly the console.log will output numbers such as below:

- 794
- 979.2000122070312
- 1243.199951171875
- 1253.199951171875
- 1252
- 1251.199951171875
- 1250
- 1250

I have a sidemenu that scrolls with the content but the problem is that when I scroll quickly it will go very jumpy.

So my question is, is there a way to detect the scroll of a user for every pixel they scroll?

Thank you

Comment: Why would I need a menu when I'm currently scrolling down a site? Wait till I've finished scrolling and then adjust the menu.

Comment: I would suggest you using the `position: fixed;` CSS property  combined with media queries to do this. What you are doing now is very intensive for the browser.

Comment: @Andreas It is what major sites such as Twitter do.

Comment: @NielsBosman Would it be possible to provide a link that shows an example?

Comment: Here's an example page that uses `position:fixed` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341897/detecting-every-pixel-of-jquery-scroll

Comment: You wouldn't really want that: It can slow down things **extremely** due to the many events that have to be processed, as I brought up in this question (and answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/46183911/5641669