# DIV fade in onscroll with JQuery but without triggering on each pixel

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg, division

I have an SVG inside a DIV that is supposed to start at 0% opacity and then fade in to 100% via jQuery when I scroll down to 800px. Currently, it's:

1. Loading at full opacity (instead of 0%) before fading out and back in again and
2. Firing repeatedly (ex. fade in on pixel 800, and again at 801, 802,
   etc.).

How would I fix this to only fire once?

**Edit:** I've adapted code that Johannes posted and replaced it below. Issue 2 is now resolved but issue 1 still remains.

```js
$var status_1 = "closed";
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollposition = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ((scrollposition > 800) && (status_1 == "closed")) {
    $('.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo').fadeIn(1000);
    status_1 = "open";
  }
  if ((scrollposition < 800) && (status_1 == "open")) {
    $('.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo').fadeOut(1000);
    status_1 = "closed";
  }
});
```

```css
.verticallogoFixed {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  left: 2.25em;
  z-index: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  /* display: none; */
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo {
  fill: #07372F;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.stickyMPlogo:hover {
  fill: #D5E900;
}

.svgLogo a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0.1vw;
  padding-right: 0.1vw;
}

.containerDemo {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerDemo">
  <div class="verticallogoFixed">
    <a href="http://melanie-patterson.com/" class="svgLogo">
      <svg class="stickyMPlogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 1200" fill="#D5E900">
        <path d="M1.743 1096.853l68.161-32.474-68.16-25.37v-14.883h.845c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.665 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.508 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H4.534l75.602 28.076c-26.546 14.613-45.364 21.15-72.388 34.503l36.279.084c20.889.682 41.93-1.119 41.437-14.207h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-77.804v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.65h36.364c-9.416-10.07.946-20.246 1.353-30.274 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.144 9.302 10.825 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.847H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-88.459h.846c0 7.274 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h60.211c-.498-10.964 2.456-42.495-13.108-44.566v-.845H86.31v60.465h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm32.22-76.533c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.059 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 855.833v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.721 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.585h.846v27.737h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 846.276c49.873-7.207 58.144 40.325 29.09 41.608-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 858.623l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.608 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.568 35.772 27.568 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.277zM1.743 799.002l72.22-47.357c-17.211.588-72.082-4.438-71.374 14.208h-.846v-22.834h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748c1.394 1.533-81.51 53.535-81.522 54.375 16.771-1.027 79.921 5.545 78.985-14.206h.846V813.8h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-61.059V715.11h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-27.907v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.07.947-20.247 1.353-30.274 0-3.214-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.635a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.651v-.846H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78zm0-95.223c.59-12.335-1.283-22.719-1.692-35.265 1.257-46.321 70.636-32.988 49.05 20.296h13.7c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.845v22.749h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm49.64-32.897C49.89 545.64-13.2 551.842 3.944 599.844h44.312a48.422 48.422 0 0 0 3.129-17.928zm-17.42-59.198c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.06 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 524.494v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.72 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.586h.846v27.738h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 514.938c49.872-7.208 58.144 40.324 29.09 41.607-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 527.284l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.607 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.569 35.772 27.569 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.278zM1.743 434.344H13.16v.845c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.491-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.103h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.625 4.53 25.641 10.57 25.116v.845H1.744zm0-64.188H13.16v.846c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.49-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.104h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.626 4.53 25.642 10.57 25.117v.845H1.744zm0-5.076v-60.548H13.16v.845c-10.478-.699-11.12 29.486-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.072.947-20.247 1.353-30.275 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.845c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.176 7.176 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.817 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.846H86.31v60.549h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm83.721-65.624c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846C2.332 287.12.461 276.739.051 264.192c-1.813-34.953 44.866-38.172 45.837-3.89-.001 7.949-5.413 13.361-5.413 16.913 0 1.015.254 2.452 2.198 2.452 5.497 0 6.681-17.843 17.337-24.693 10.401-6.68 25.454-14.545 25.454-24.186h.846c.051 20.223 3.24 13.081-25.37 32.558-12.347 8.203-12.685 17.167-18.435 17.167a2.722 2.722 0 0 1-2.876-2.96c0-4.99 4.82-8.88 4.82-16.744-2.227-27.942-56.286-24.068-40.507 23.678H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.748zM.052 192.9a70.913 70.913 0 0 1 3.89-24.1h11.332v.845S1.067 174.803 1.067 192.9c0 15.73 9.556 24.355 18.943 24.355 23.17 0 14.968-53.446 44.566-53.446 11.755 0 23.425 12.178 23.425 31.713 0 11.163-5.666 21.057-10.317 27.315H66.352c-.889-1.528 20.155-10.893 20.126-32.05 0-12.348-9.048-22.073-18.435-22.073-25.454 0-18.266 54.46-46.004 54.46C10.285 223.176.052 212.436.052 192.9zm43.975-39.24c-58.094-.207-58.089-75.063 0-75.264 58.094.206 58.088 75.062 0 75.263zm0-7.612c56.683-.588 56.678-59.456-.002-60.041-56.851-.33-56.846 60.376.002 60.041zM1.743 55.983l72.22-47.357C56.752 9.213 1.882 4.188 2.59 22.833h-.846V0h.846c0 7.272 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748C89.392 9.309 6.494 61.318 6.48 62.156 23.251 61.129 86.4 67.7 85.464 47.949h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846z" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

[revised jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1yc5x32/1/),
[original version jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krw27sbx/)

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar question once and later found an answer to it myself, which you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185584/5641669 Maybe it can help you.

Comment: @Johannes This was great, thanks! It now goes off only once. I need to find proper documentation on how to load the SVG as hidden. I've spent the past couple of days looking but I'm seeing mixed information and haven't had success yet.

Comment: Better outsource the function, and call it with window (instead of this), to run it when the page loads. So it would be like: $(window).scoll(handleFade); handleFade();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also achieve this fade animation by **toggling classes** ("opened", "closed"):

```js
let logo = $('.stickyMPlogo');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollposition = $(this).scrollTop();
  let closed = logo.hasClass('closed');
  //fade in
  if ((scrollposition > 800) && closed ) {
    logo.toggleClass('closed opened')
    console.log('open')
  }
  //fade out
  else if ((scrollposition < 800) && !closed ) {
    logo.toggleClass('opened closed')
    console.log('close')
  } 
});
```

```css
.verticallogoFixed {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  left: 2.25em;
  z-index: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  /* display: none; */
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo {
  fill: #07372F;
  transition: 1s;
}

.stickyMPlogo:hover {
  fill: #D5E900;
}

.svgLogo a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0.1vw;
  padding-right: 0.1vw;
}

.containerDemo {
  height: 2000px;
}


.stickyMPlogo{
  transition:0.5s;
}

.closed{
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.opened{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll down to fade in logo</p>
<div class="containerDemo">
  <div class="verticallogoFixed"><a href="http://melanie-patterson.com/" class="svgLogo"><svg class="stickyMPlogo closed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 1200" fill="#D5E900">
        <path d="m1.7 1096.9 68.2-32.5L1.7 1039v-14.9h.9c0 7.3 6 7.8 22.7 7.8h37.5c16.7 0 22.7-.5 22.7-7.8h.8v22.9h-.8c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H4.5l75.6 28c-26.5 14.7-45.3 21.2-72.4 34.6H44c21 .7 42-1 41.5-14.2h.8v22.9h-.8c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.8h-.9zm0-77.9v-60.5h11.5v.8C2.7 958.6 2 988.8 2.6 1004H39c-9.5-10 .9-20.3 1.3-30.3 0-3.2-1.9-6.2-4.8-6.2v-.9c5 0 9.3 4.2 9.3 10.8 0 10.4-7.3 14.7-7.5 20.7a7.2 7.2 0 0 0 3 5.9h45.2c-.5-10.8 2.3-42.8-13.1-44.7v-.8h14v60.5h-1c0-7.2-6-7.7-22.6-7.7H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.7zm0-88.4h.9c0 7.3 6 7.8 22.7 7.8h60.2c-.5-11 2.4-42.5-13.1-44.6v-.8h14v60.4h-1c0-7.2-6-7.8-22.6-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.6-22.7 7.8h-.9zM34 854c-1.6 0-2.3.9-2.3 2 0 4 8.9 6.6 8.9 11.4 0 2.4-2.3 2.8-4.5 2L0 855.7v-.8l71.4-27c9.3-3.8 14-6.5 14-11.7h.8V844h-.8c0-12-6.9-11.5-15.4-8.3l-27.7 10.5c49.9-7.2 58.2 40.3 29.1 41.6-20.8 0-28.7-33.8-37.5-33.8zm50 13.3c-.7-20-31.4-23.7-47.2-19l-27 10.2 26 9.7c2.9 1.1 4 .5 4-.9 0-3.9-9-7-9-11.5 0-1.6 1.1-2.8 3.3-2.8 11.4 0 15 27.6 35.8 27.6 8 0 14-5 14-13.3zM1.6 799 74 751.6c-17.2.6-72.1-4.4-71.4 14.3h-.9V743h.9c0 7.3 6 7.8 22.7 7.8H88c1.4 1.5-81.5 53.5-81.5 54.4 16.8-1 79.9 5.5 79-14.2h.8v22.8h-.8c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.8h-.9zm0-61v-23h.9c0 7.3 6 7.8 22.7 7.8h37.5c16.7 0 22.7-.5 22.7-7.8h.8v23h-.8c0-7.2-6-7.7-22.7-7.7H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.7zm0-28v-60.5h11.5v.8C2.7 649.6 2 679.8 2.6 695H39c-9.5-10 .9-20.3 1.3-30.3 0-3.2-1.9-6.2-4.8-6.2v-.9c5 0 9.3 4.1 9.3 10.8 0 10.3-7.3 14.7-7.5 20.7a7.2 7.2 0 0 0 3 5.9h45.2c-.5-10.8 2.3-42.8-13.1-44.7v-.8h14V710h-1c0-7.2-6-7.7-22.6-7.7H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.7zm0-95.2c.6-12.3-1.2-22.7-1.6-35.3 1.2-46.3 70.6-33 49 20.3h13.7c16.7 0 22.7-.5 22.7-7.7h.8v22.7h-.8c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.8zM51.4 582c-1.5-36.3-64.6-30-47.5 18h44.4a48.4 48.4 0 0 0 3-18zM34 522.7c-1.6 0-2.3 1-2.3 2 0 4.1 8.9 6.6 8.9 11.5 0 2.3-2.3 2.8-4.5 2L0 524.4v-.9l71.4-27c9.3-3.7 14-6.4 14-11.6h.8v27.7h-.8c0-11.9-6.9-11.5-15.4-8.2l-27.7 10.4c49.9-7.2 58.2 40.4 29.1 41.6-20.8 0-28.7-33.8-37.5-33.8zm50 13.4c-.7-20-31.4-23.8-47.2-19l-27 10.2 26 9.7c2.9 1.1 4 .4 4-1 0-3.8-9-7-9-11.4 0-1.6 1.1-2.8 3.3-2.8 11.4 0 15 27.6 35.8 27.6 8 0 14-5 14-13.3zM1.6 434.3h11.5v.9c-6-.5-10.5 10.5-10.6 25.1h60.2c16.7 0 22.7.2 22.7-7.1h.8v22h-.8c0-7.2-6-7.7-22.7-7.7H2.6C2.6 482 7 493 13.2 492.6v.9H1.7zm0-64.1h11.5v.8c-6-.5-10.5 10.5-10.6 25.1h60.2c16.7 0 22.7.2 22.7-7h.8v22h-.8c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H2.6C2.6 418 7 429 13.2 428.4v.9H1.7zm0-5.1v-60.6h11.5v.9C2.7 304.7 2 334.9 2.6 350H39c-9.5-10 .9-20.2 1.3-30.2 0-3.3-1.9-6.3-4.8-6.3v-.8c5 0 9.3 4 9.3 10.8 0 10.3-7.3 14.6-7.5 20.6a7.2 7.2 0 0 0 3 6h45.2c-.5-10.9 2.3-42.9-13.1-44.7v-.9h14v60.6h-1c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.6-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.8zm83.8-65.6c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.8h-.9C2.3 287 .5 276.7.1 264.2c-1.9-35 44.8-38.2 45.8-3.9 0 8-5.4 13.4-5.4 17 0 1 .2 2.4 2.2 2.4 5.5 0 6.7-17.9 17.3-24.7 10.4-6.7 25.5-14.6 25.5-24.2h.8c0 20.2 3.3 13-25.4 32.5-12.3 8.2-12.6 17.2-18.4 17.2a2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.9-3c0-5 4.8-8.8 4.8-16.7-2.2-28-56.2-24-40.5 23.7h58.9c16.7 0 22.7-.5 22.7-7.8h.8v22.8zM0 192.9a71 71 0 0 1 3.8-24.1h11.4v.8S1 174.8 1 193c0 15.7 9.5 24.4 19 24.4 23 0 14.9-53.5 44.5-53.5 11.7 0 23.4 12.2 23.4 31.7a48 48 0 0 1-10.3 27.3H66.4c-1-1.5 20.1-10.9 20-32 0-12.4-9-22-18.4-22-25.4 0-18.2 54.4-46 54.4-11.7 0-22-10.8-22-30.3zm44-39.2c-58.2-.2-58.2-75.1 0-75.3 58 .2 58 75 0 75.3zm0-7.7c56.6-.5 56.6-59.4 0-60-57-.3-57 60.4 0 60zM1.6 56 74 8.6C56.8 9.2 1.9 4.2 2.6 22.8h-.9V0h.9c0 7.3 6 7.8 22.7 7.8H88C89.4 9.3 6.5 61.3 6.5 62.2c16.8-1 79.9 5.5 79-14.3h.8v22.9h-.8c0-7.3-6-7.8-22.7-7.8H25.3c-16.7 0-22.7.5-22.7 7.8h-.9z" />
      </svg></a></div>
  <div class="content" />
</div>
```

The 2 classes "opened" and "closed" will set opacity.
`transition` will change the transition (fading) speed.

```
.stickyMPlogo {
  fill: #07372F;
  transition: 1s;
}

.closed{
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.opened{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

and indicate the current state checked on scroll via `hasClass()` method

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Very clean!

Answer (score 1):

You can use animate to show or hide as FadeOut/FadeIn method immediately removes/adds element from its place, while animate will also animate the place it is placed in. See if below works for you!

```js
var status_1 = "closed";
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollposition = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ((scrollposition > 800) && (status_1 == "closed")) {
    $('.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo').animate({opacity:1},1000);
    status_1 = "open";
  }
  if ((scrollposition < 800) && (status_1 == "open")) {
    $('.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo').animate({opacity:0},1000);
    status_1 = "closed";
  }
});
```

```css
.verticallogoFixed {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  left: 2.25em;
  z-index: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  /* display: none; */
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo {
  fill: #07372F;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.stickyMPlogo:hover {
  fill: #D5E900;
}

.svgLogo a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0.1vw;
  padding-right: 0.1vw;
}

.containerDemo {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerDemo">
  <div class="verticallogoFixed">
    <a href="http://melanie-patterson.com/" class="svgLogo">
      <svg class="stickyMPlogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 1200" fill="#D5E900">
        <path d="M1.743 1096.853l68.161-32.474-68.16-25.37v-14.883h.845c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.665 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.508 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H4.534l75.602 28.076c-26.546 14.613-45.364 21.15-72.388 34.503l36.279.084c20.889.682 41.93-1.119 41.437-14.207h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-77.804v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.65h36.364c-9.416-10.07.946-20.246 1.353-30.274 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.144 9.302 10.825 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.847H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-88.459h.846c0 7.274 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h60.211c-.498-10.964 2.456-42.495-13.108-44.566v-.845H86.31v60.465h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm32.22-76.533c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.059 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 855.833v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.721 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.585h.846v27.737h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 846.276c49.873-7.207 58.144 40.325 29.09 41.608-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 858.623l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.608 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.568 35.772 27.568 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.277zM1.743 799.002l72.22-47.357c-17.211.588-72.082-4.438-71.374 14.208h-.846v-22.834h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748c1.394 1.533-81.51 53.535-81.522 54.375 16.771-1.027 79.921 5.545 78.985-14.206h.846V813.8h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-61.059V715.11h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-27.907v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.07.947-20.247 1.353-30.274 0-3.214-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.635a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.651v-.846H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78zm0-95.223c.59-12.335-1.283-22.719-1.692-35.265 1.257-46.321 70.636-32.988 49.05 20.296h13.7c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.845v22.749h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm49.64-32.897C49.89 545.64-13.2 551.842 3.944 599.844h44.312a48.422 48.422 0 0 0 3.129-17.928zm-17.42-59.198c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.06 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 524.494v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.72 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.586h.846v27.738h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 514.938c49.872-7.208 58.144 40.324 29.09 41.607-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 527.284l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.607 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.569 35.772 27.569 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.278zM1.743 434.344H13.16v.845c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.491-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.103h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.625 4.53 25.641 10.57 25.116v.845H1.744zm0-64.188H13.16v.846c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.49-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.104h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.626 4.53 25.642 10.57 25.117v.845H1.744zm0-5.076v-60.548H13.16v.845c-10.478-.699-11.12 29.486-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.072.947-20.247 1.353-30.275 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.845c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.176 7.176 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.817 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.846H86.31v60.549h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm83.721-65.624c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846C2.332 287.12.461 276.739.051 264.192c-1.813-34.953 44.866-38.172 45.837-3.89-.001 7.949-5.413 13.361-5.413 16.913 0 1.015.254 2.452 2.198 2.452 5.497 0 6.681-17.843 17.337-24.693 10.401-6.68 25.454-14.545 25.454-24.186h.846c.051 20.223 3.24 13.081-25.37 32.558-12.347 8.203-12.685 17.167-18.435 17.167a2.722 2.722 0 0 1-2.876-2.96c0-4.99 4.82-8.88 4.82-16.744-2.227-27.942-56.286-24.068-40.507 23.678H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.748zM.052 192.9a70.913 70.913 0 0 1 3.89-24.1h11.332v.845S1.067 174.803 1.067 192.9c0 15.73 9.556 24.355 18.943 24.355 23.17 0 14.968-53.446 44.566-53.446 11.755 0 23.425 12.178 23.425 31.713 0 11.163-5.666 21.057-10.317 27.315H66.352c-.889-1.528 20.155-10.893 20.126-32.05 0-12.348-9.048-22.073-18.435-22.073-25.454 0-18.266 54.46-46.004 54.46C10.285 223.176.052 212.436.052 192.9zm43.975-39.24c-58.094-.207-58.089-75.063 0-75.264 58.094.206 58.088 75.062 0 75.263zm0-7.612c56.683-.588 56.678-59.456-.002-60.041-56.851-.33-56.846 60.376.002 60.041zM1.743 55.983l72.22-47.357C56.752 9.213 1.882 4.188 2.59 22.833h-.846V0h.846c0 7.272 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748C89.392 9.309 6.494 61.318 6.48 62.156 23.251 61.129 86.4 67.7 85.464 47.949h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846z" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works once I add ``opacity: 0;`` to ``.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo``! Thanks...appreciate the info on fadeIn/fadeOut vs animate, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to svg

```
style="display:none"
```

or add a javascript for hide the svg at the startup after var status_1 declaration

```
if (($(this).scrollTop() < 800) && (status_1 == "closed")) {
     $('.stickyMPlogo').fadeOut(1000);
     status_1 = "closed";
}
```

Also here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnbtx3zh/)

Comment: This is close! Starts perfectly but when the 800 `scrollTop` comes in, it momentarily starts out at 100% opacity and then starts over and fades in from 0% opacity.

Comment: Let me understand better, u want that the opacity start from 800 scrollTop and gradually increases?

Comment: I'm looking for 0% opacity @ 0 ``scrollTop``  and then 100% opacity w/ ``fadeIn`` starting at 800 ``scrollTop``.